# Is there a way to get frame number in Silverlight MediaElement object?

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [silverlight media player with frame counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786712/silverlight-media-player-with-frame-counter)

We want to know whether we can get frame number?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the frames per second (FPS) then you multiply the FPS times the position in the media.  MediaElement does not have a way to directly query the FPS.