# Silverlight media player with frame counter

Tags: silverlight

I am trying to write a simple Silverlight media player, but I need the timestamp to be hh:mm:ss:ff where FF is Frame count.

I used a timer in order to get ticks and calculate the frame I am in, but it seems very inaccurate.
How can I count reliably the frame I am in?

Does anyone know of a free Silverlight player that will do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193989/is-there-a-way-to-get-frame-number-in-silverlight-mediaelement-object

Comment: its very abstract to say multiply FPS in position. what exaclty to multiply in the position???

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight is designed to update at irregular intervals and catch-up any animation or media playing to the current elapsed time when the next frame is rendered.

To calculate the current frame (a frame is just a specific fraction of a second) it is simply a matter of multiplying total *elapsed* time, *since the playback started*, by the number of *frames-per-second* encoded in the video then finding the *remainder* of frames within that second to get the current frame.

**e.g. 
Current frame = (Elapsed-Time-in-seconds * FramesPerSecond) % FramesPerSecond;**

So if 20.12 seconds has elapsed, on a video that has 24 frames per second, you are on Frame 482 (actually 482.88 but only whole frames matter).

Take the Modulus of that by the Frames-per-second and you get the remaining number of frames (e.g. 2) so you are on frame number 2 in second number 20 (or 00:00:20:02).

You need to do the multiply using doubles (or floats) and the final modulus on an integer value so it will be like this in C# code:

```
int framesPerSecond = 24; // for example
double elapsedTimeInSeconds = ...; /// Get the elapsed time...
int currentFrame = ((int)(elapsedTimeInSeconds * (double)framesPerSecond)) % framesPerSecond;
```

As the question has changed (in comment) to a fractional frame rate the maths will be as per this console app:

```
using System;

namespace TimeTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double framesPerSecond = 29.97;

            for (double elapsedTime = 0; elapsedTime < 5; elapsedTime+=0.01)
            {
                int currentFrame = (int)((elapsedTime*framesPerSecond) % framesPerSecond);
                Console.WriteLine("Time: {0} = Frame: {1}", elapsedTime, currentFrame);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: You are not guaranteed to display every frame number, as the framerate is not perfect, but you can only see the rendered frames so it does not matter. The frames you see will have the correct frame numbers.*

Comment: Thanks. I did a similar formula already diving by ticks and not seconds. but its the same. I am experiencing with your formula the same problem i had already, the current frame is double eventually, and after it reaches something like frame 20.48, the real frame is 1 behind... this is because its accumulative offset, and is being dragged over the movie time... and then there is a big offset of 1-2 frames

Comment: @Himberjack: If a one of 2 frame difference is that important to your app you might want to rethink the delivery method. Frames do occasionally get dropped in Silverlight (and every other web-based video player). What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to do subtitle editing website.. when using FPS of 24/25 your solution works, but in 29.97 it does act a bit wierd.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include the maths for fractional frame-rate (I forgot modulus in C# also works for doubles) :) This version should work for any case now, but there may be a slight rounding error introduced by the modulus.

Comment: thanks but it still doesnt help... I rewarded the bounty for your kind help. I think its just SL limitations after all